# Boolean SAT problem (NP-complete)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, computational-complexity

I’m trying to get my head around exactly what this problem is asking. The part I’m struggling with is how we measure complexity of the problem.

Would $(a\implies b)$ be regarded as less complicated than $(a \wedge b) \vee (a \implies b)$

Is the complexity measured by the number of logical operations or by the number of variables in the expression or by the number of different variables or by the number of symbols?

Thanks in advance, Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways of measuring the size of a problem, but essentially it is the number of bits used to express it.  So yes, $(a \implies b)$ would be smaller than $(a \wedge b) \vee (a \implies b)$ (even though they turn out to be logically equivalent).

Comment: A follow up question if you don’t mind, would a solution to the SAT problem tell you what a solution is or tell you how many there are or tell you that a solution exists? - I have developed a way to convert a logical statement into a number that tells you how many ways it can be satisfied, but does not tell you what the solutions are.

Comment: The classical SAT problem is a decision problem, so a solution just tells you whether a solution exists.  However, finding a solution is not much harder: if you know that a solution exists, then you solve the problem with variable #1 set to "true" to see if there is a solution where that variable is true: if so, you next see whether there is a solution with variable #1 "true" and variable #2 "true", if not you see whether there is a solution with variable #1 "false" and variable #2 "true", etc.

Comment: Counting the number of solutions, on the other hand, is thought to be much harder: #P-complete.

Comment: I have a method which does just that. - produces the number of solutions. Does the input need to be in Conjunctive Normal Form, or can it be any Boolean variation? I have created my own variation for my method to be fast. From here I only need multiplication (which is fast) and numerical substitution (which is fast). I’m trying to ascertain whether or not my method says anything about P vs NP but I know so little about the technical details.

Comment: The classical problem allows inputs in any form.  There are many variants though, e.g. CNF-SAT where the inputs are in conjunctive normal form.  If the input is in disjunctive normal form (DNF), the decision problem is easy but the counting problem is still hard.